# Adobe Illustrator Scripting - Change Color of Selection

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm trying to set the colour of my current selection in Illustrator using a .jsx script.

I can't find documentation on changing styles on (selected) objects. I have read most documentation out there, but I can't seem to find such a "simple" thing anywhere. Here is the code I've come up with:

```
thisThing = app.activeDocument.selection[0];
thisThing.filled = true;
thisThing.fillColor = '#ff0000';
```

When I run it, nothing happens sadly.

Comment: AFAIK, colours are either CMYK, RGB, Greyscale or Lab. See the [AI scripting reference](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html) for more info

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but i posted this after not finding anything in the references. I have found a solution online meanwhile, will post it in case anyone has a similiar problem.

Comment: Page 25 of [this PDF](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/illustrator/pdf/Illustrator_JavaScript_Scripting_Reference_2017.pdf) gives you a good example

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thank you for your reply! I was mainly wondering how to apply a style to the currenct selection, without creating an item to apply it to. I suppose doc.graphicstyles[x].applyTo(app.selection[0]) might work?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out a solution - it works, but it's very messy (due to being an edited solution). This gives a random grey colour to the selected item:

```
var myGrey= new CMYKColor()
myGrey.black=((Math.random()*80)+10);

if (app.documents.length && app.selection.length)  
{  
     for (var a=0; a<app.selection.length; a++)  
     {  
          try {  
               app.selection[a].fillColor = myGrey;  
          } catch (e)  
          {  
               // ignoring all possible errors ...  
          }  
     }  
}
```

In case you want to do non-grayscale: add myGrey.Yellow = value between 1-100;